# Sequalize adds primary key to query implicitly

Tags: javascript, database, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize-typescript and it implicitly adds primary key column to all create queries which is a problem because I don't want to set this id by myself (IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF).

```
@Table({
  timestamps: false,
})
class Table extends Model<Table> {
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column
  MyId: string;
  @Column
  column: string;
}
table.create({column: 'value'});
```

This ends up with query:

```
sql: 'INSERT INTO [Table] ([MyId],[column]) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES (NULL,'value');'
```

And error:

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values.
```

The query I need to get is:

```
INSERT INTO [Table] ([column]) OUTPUT INSERTED.* VALUES ('value');
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - remove @PrimaryKey decorator.
After model is added to sequelize instance do next:

```
Table.removeAttribute('id');
```

Now id won't be added to queries but will be used for ordering in select methods so set your own order by:

```
Table.findAll({where: {column: 'value'}, order: ['MyId']});
```

And of course using this means that your DB knows which column is primary key and increments it by itself.